# Truecrypt on Linux (permission confusion)

Tags: linux, permissions, truecrypt

I am pretty inexperienced with Linux... So please bear with me here.

I keep running into permission problems when working with `truecrypt` on Linux. Currently, I run `truecrypt` as root to mount my encrypted devices and containers. This all works fine, but I have to interact with the mounted volumes in the terminal as root, and I can't seem to use many of my applications on the files... Either because they can't be run as root or I don't know how to use them from the terminal. This seems really inconvenient to me.

How do people deal with this? Am I missing something, or is this just the way things have to be?

I am on Fedora 17 (KDE spin) now but I have this trouble with any distro I try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the SUID isn't set with root ownership.

```
ls -l /usr/bin/truecrypt
```

On your system will give an output like:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root
```

To set the SUID type:

```
chmod u+s /usr/bin/truecrypt
```

Now 'ls -l' should look like this:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root
```

When an executable is given SUID permissions, whenever the executable is launched the resulting process will have the ownership of the owner of the executable, not the person launching the process.

Comment: If all you want is setuid, it's usually better to use `chmod u+s FILE` instead of, say, `chmod 4755 FILE`. This because if you use the `u+s` syntax, it won't touch any of the other permission bits.

Comment: Yes that might be true. But if he already touched the file this will set it to the default value and set the SUID.

Comment: If the permissions were incorrect, it's unlikely (though not impossible) that by pure chance they'd be set to executable. In which case the OP wouldn't be able to mount the encrypted device in the first place, and the question would have looked very different.

Comment: Ok you are right thanks Michael. just changed it.

Comment: hmm, truecrypt tells me that setuid doesn't work with gtk:
http://www.gtk.org/setuid.html
I guess it can be argued that this shouldn't be done anyways:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/68327/why-does-truecrypt-ask-for-administrator-password